# PerspectiveTransform not working properly

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I've an image which contains a chessboard image upon a rectangular object of interest. The image might be taken at any angle using a phone camera. Using the chessboard I'm trying to correct the perspective of the object of interest. But I'm not getting success with it.

Here, is the output [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xSjm5Ww2Bn2TOvF8rWmHs8bIoGxmIiRt). If one draws a rectangle over the chessboard using photoshop, it can be seen that it's coming out to be a perfect rectangle but when a rectangle is fitted over the object, it's not perfect.

Why is this happening?

```
rows = 9
cols = 6
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 30, 0.001)
flags = 0
flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH
flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK
flags |= cv2.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE

def calibrate(image):
    img = image.copy()
    objectPoints = np.zeros((rows * cols, 3), np.float32)
    objectPoints[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:rows, 0:cols].T.reshape(-1, 2)
    objectPointsArray = []
    imgPointsArray = []
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (rows, cols), flags=flags)

    # Make sure the chess board pattern was found in the image
    if ret:
        # Refine the corner position
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)

        # Add the object points and the image points to the arrays
        objectPointsArray.append(objectPoints)
        imgPointsArray.append(corners)

        # Draw the corners on the image
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (rows, cols), corners, ret)
        plt.imshow(img)
        cv2.imwrite('out.jpg', img)
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objectPointsArray, imgPointsArray, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
    for i in range(len(objectPointsArray)):
        imgPoints, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objectPointsArray[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], mtx, dist)
    return imgPoints, ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs

imgPoints, ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = calibrate(_roi)

imgPoints = np.squeeze(imgPoints)
p1 = imgPoints[0]
p2 = imgPoints[8]
p3 = imgPoints[-9]
p4 = imgPoints[-1]

pts = np.stack([p1,p2,p3,p4])
screenCnt = order_points(pts)
pts1 = np.float32(screenCnt)

ratio=0.625
cardH=math.sqrt((pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])*(pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])+(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1])*(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1]))
cardW=ratio*cardH;
pts2 = np.float32([[pts1[0][0],pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]+cardH], [pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1]+cardH]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

transformed = np.zeros((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), dtype=np.uint8);
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, transformed.shape)
```

Comment: for testing, can you try to use a subimage with the chessboard-paper on the door? Maybe chessboard detection assumes a bigger part of the image to contain the pattern, or doesn work with very high resolution images, etc.

Comment: @Micka actually I'm cropping the image first before feeding it to the detection algorithm `calibrate(_roi)`. So, the detection algorithm is working pretty descent in my case.